# JSF 1.2 lifecycle details

Tags: page-lifecycle, jsf-1.2

I would like to ask 2 questions on JSF 1.2 lifecycle:

- All the requests for jsf resources are managed by the FacesServlet whose service method
  starts the lifecycle for the requested resource. So, for each request:

  - the web container creates a new thread to serve the request
  - the thread calls the service method of the FacesServlet which starts jsf lifecycle
  - the whole lifecylce runs into the thread

  Is this correct?
- JSF pages are translated into servlet at a certain point of the lifecycle or not?
  Talking about the Render Response Phase, the JavaEE 5 tutorial says: "During this phase,
  the JavaServer Faces implementation delegates authority for rendering the page to the JSP
  container if the application is using JSP pages ..... the components will render themselves
  as the JSP container traverses the tags in the page."

  Does it mean that the response is constructed one tag at a time while the jsp container
  traverses the whole view without the need to translate the page into a servlet and call
  the resulting jsp_service method (as for standard jsp pages)?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Nico

Comment: I got a partial answer here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2406412&tstart=0

Comment: I got a good answer here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/585340/JSF/java/JSF-lifecycle-details